# A complex eight pieces opposite color Bishop endgame

Tags: analysis, endgame, evaluation, bishop-endgame

The position, derivated by a variation of the Alechkine Defense, Four Pawns Attack, is the following:

```
[FEN "3b4/8/1k2B3/6pK/P7/8/6PP/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

Black to move. Stockfish 14.1 NNUE gives White +1.70 but White can make no progress as far as I can see. May someone try with either a software with tablebases incorporated (mine is not) or FinalGen give me a clue? It is really a draw or the win is simply very distant?

Comment: Just a side note: Lichess Stockfish 14+ NNUE gave +1.2 on depth 61.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is fairly easy to analyze with some tablebase help.

First of all, it is obvious White must make a second free pawn to
"scissor" Black. There are exactly two options:

1.g3 any 2.h4 gxh4 3.gxh4. Now White has TWO edge pawns.
Immediately we see Black is set up totally wrong:
the king must hold the h-pawn, which is the "wrong" one (queening
on the non-bishop color) and the bishop, if necessary, sacrifice
against the a-pawn.

Playing a few pass moves before the exchange on h4, we see that
Black should not idle too much: After gxh4, the game is won for
White with the K on, say, a7, as even a 6-piecer verifies.
But b6 suffices.

Much more dangerous is playing 1.g4 any 2.h4 gxh4 3.g5. This
endgame is won if White can capture the h pawn before it runs
and deflects the bishop from the defense of the a pawn.
Which means Black should position the king on b4 (where it
attacks the pawn and is closest to the king side if White
changes mind). But a5 is OK too. White can play g3 first
to have the option h4 like in the first variant, but even
with Ka5, it is draw as the "on-the-fly" attack on the Bd7
(only square - otherwise in variant 2 either the Pa4 is
not protected or the black h-pawn runs) gets Black another
tempo.

Coda: Draw with precise play from Black (play Ka5-b4-a5
ad nauseam; if variant 2, h3 draws immediately, if
variant 1, run for your life to the kingside - if White
manages a setup Kg6/Bc4 before Black played Kg8, win).

Comment: I think you rather wait with Kc5-b4-c5 unless White plays g4, after e.g. 1...Ka5 2.Bd7 Kb4 3.Bb5 Ka5 4.g3 Kb4 5.Kg4, then 5...Ka5? 6.h4 loses while 5...Kc5! might be the only drawing move : 6.h4 gh 7.gh Kd6 8.h5 Ke7 9.Kf5 Kf7=.

Comment: @Evargalo: You cheated, you played Kg4 and won a move :-) (Of course I immediately play Kc5 when g4 is no longer a threat...)

Comment: I half-cheated, but even with the wK on h5 you can have issues: 1...Ka5 2.Bb3 Kb4 3.Bc2 Ka5 4.g3 Kb4 5.Bd1 is an attempt to put Black in zugzwang : 5...Ka5? 6.h4!+-, but 5...Kc5! 6.g4 Kb4 7.h4 gh4 8.g5 Bxg5=

Comment: @Evargalo: Agreed, I would exactly try this in a last attempt to swindling out a win :-)